# Validating Problem - Doesn't work in IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using following Code to add status-messages via PHP & Javascript (Ajax):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#status_form").submit(function(){
        var s_autor =   $('#s_autor').attr('value');
        var s_status    =   $('#s_status').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/request.php",
            data: "s_autor="+ s_autor +"& s_status="+ s_status,
            success: function() {
                $('#show').load("/request.php", function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn("slow", function() {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#show").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                                $("#show").slideUp("slow", function() {
                                    $("#s_status").val("Statusnachricht", function() {
                                        $(this).empty();
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        }, 2000);
                    });
                }); 
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

After a friend telling me it doesn't work in IE, I used JSLint to validate the Code... JSLint gave me this Report:

```
    Error:

Implied global: $ 1,2,3,4,5,10,11,13,15,16,17, document 1, setTimeout 12
```

Does someone know how to correct this error? I really don't know how to change it correctly... Would be awesome if you could help me : )

Comment: This is horribly unreadable. I suggest splitting out some of these callbacks into separate functions to give you and us a better chance of working out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the space character in the line :

```
data: "s_autor="+ s_autor +"& s_status="+ s_status,
```

between the "&" and s_status.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a strange parsing error. Have you tried changing all your single quotes to double quotes?

For example change all strings like $('#show') to $("#show").